# Is it good to create multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 kinds of documents:

```
{
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2,
    category: cpp
}
```

and

```
{
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2,
    category: cs
}
```

I have around 300000 documents belonging to the 1st category (cpp) and around 400000 documents for 2nd category (cs). In both cases all fields are the same except for `category`.

Which option will be faster for read operations:

1. Creating a separate collections for each category
2. Having only one collection and adding an index on the `category` field.

Comment: You will need to tell us more about your read patterns. Do you e.g. need documents of both categories in a single query? What about non-functional topics like backups or security or additional performance, e.g. indexes on individual fields?

Comment: @dnickless 1. I can use different queries for different documents. 2. I can add index on this field (category), but will that be faster ?

Comment: No, it won't. If you keep all your documents in the same collection and need to filter upon every query then that filtering is going to cost - nothing comes for free... ;) So if those docs bear no relation to each other apart from the fact that they happen to have similar fields at this stage then by all means put them into separate collections!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to stick to single collection and add a [Single Field Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) on category. Obviously when you read, it will scan only related documents. Further to improve performance, you can implement [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#advantages-of-sharding)